# Jmeter select random product from sql server db

Tags: jmeter

I have a CompanyID value being read into my Jmeter script, is it possible to then get it to do a sql query and select a random product from the results

Comment: Can you use sql for select a product random?

Comment: oh am willing to do that if it's possible but then is it able to be tied into jmeter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [JDBC Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-db-test-plan.html) to make a request in your database and select a only product random. [Here](http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/65143-using-jdbc-sampler-in-jmeter-2-6) a good explanation about JDBC Sampler.

For make a sql to select random itens, you can see [here](http://www.petefreitag.com/item/466.cfm)